# X axis interval limit change in “twoord.plot”

Tags: r

How can be X axis interval limit change in “twoord.plot” from default/auto to the manual limit (as user want)? 
Say for example if we plot a graph range of x axis from 1600 to 2000 so it takes point like 1600, 1700 1800, 1900 and 2000 automatically and now, if we want x axis interval should be in the 50 year instead of 100 so what would be the exact command or argument to change it accordingly ?

```
 twoord.plot(ABC$Year, ABC$season, ABC$year, ABC$month,data=NULL, xlim =c(1570,2020), lylim = c(0,2), rylim = c(0,20),lcol = 1, rcol = 2, xlab = "Years", lytickpos = NA, ylab = "sesons", ylab.at= NA, rytickpos = NA, rylab = "month", rylab.at = NA, lpch = 1,rpch = 2,type = "l")
```

Problem is in x-axis interval, i simply want 50-50 year increment but by default  it takes  100 years.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just edited my question to make it more clear and specific. hope it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add this line and make it work. Make changes according to your code.

Use **at** and **Seq** to define the axis labels:

```
 axis(1, at = seq(1570, 2020, by = 50), las=2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. actually i did the same but one issue with that, when we use the above said argument extra axis added with the plot. I do not want extra axis because of overlapping line. Due to this problem i posted the questions.

Comment: can you post the output here?